# Adding new items to list removes old items

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello Flutter experts,

I'm new to flutter and love coding it. I'm having a strange problem: when I add an item to a list of items, old items are overwritten but the count is correct. for example, I added (name: phone, qty: 1, price: 99.99) result is same but when I add (name: shirt, qty: 2, price: 49.99) result is

1. (name: shirt, qty: 2, price: 49.99)
2. (name: shirt, qty: 2, price: 49.99)

so the first record is gone.

Please check the code segment below.

can you pls tell me what the wrong I'm doing?

Thanks,
-Naveed

```
List<ParcelItem> parcelItems = List<ParcelItem>();

void addParcelItem(ParcelItem pi ){
  parcelItems.add(pi);
}
Widget getItemList(){

List<Widget> widgetItems = List<Widget>();
for(ParcelItem itm in parcelItems){

  Widget widgetItem = Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Text(itm.name),
      Text(itm.description),
      Text(itm.quantity.toString()),
      Text(itm.price.toString()),
    ],
  );
  widgetItems.add(widgetItem);
}
if(widgetItems != null){
  return Column(
    children: widgetItems,
  );
}else{
  return Text('Add some items', style: kInstructionText,);
}
```

}

Comment: upload more code please

Comment: is your list loaded once or reloaded more than once ?

Comment: show your complete code. looks like you have made somewhere

Comment: First, how do you know that the first record is gone, did you print on console? Coz, if you checked only UI, seems you are not refreshing UI properly.

Comment: Still your code looks incomplete. Most probably the issue is you're re initializing ``List<ParcelItem> parcelItems = List<ParcelItem>();`` again and again which is causing the old values to lose. You should only initialize it only once.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the problem and fixed it!

"void addParcelItem(ParcelItem pi )" pi was a reference to a variable that was initialized once and was being used again n again. Dart was adding a reference to the same variable again n again so deleted old data but add twice to list. I fixed it by creating ParcelItem object at the time when I added item to list.

Thank you guys for your help

-Naveed

Answer (score -1):

Try the following code instead of returning `Column` :

```
 return ListView(
                    children: widgetItems.map((element) {
                      return element;
                    }).toList(),
                  ),
```

Basically what the problem seems to be is you're just returning a single `Column` and not all present in `widgetItems`